# Java "params" in method signature?

Tags: java, variadic-functions, parameters, method-declaration

In C#, if you want a method to have an indeterminate number of parameters, you can make the final parameter in the method signature a `params` so that the method parameter looks like an array but allows everyone using the method to pass as many parameters of that type as the caller wants.

I'm fairly sure Java supports similar behaviour, but I cant find out how to do it.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

In Java it's called [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), and the syntax looks like a regular parameter, but with an ellipsis ("...") after the type:

```
public void foo(Object... bar) {
    for (Object baz : bar) {
        System.out.println(baz.toString());
    }
}
```

The vararg parameter must *always* be the **last** parameter in the method signature, and is accessed as if you received an array of that type (e.g. `Object[]` in this case).

Comment: Thanks I bizzarrly found this out myself while I was looking up something else, and was coming here to answer the question myself.

Comment: Note that the ellipse is three periods (correctly typed in the answer as ...) and not an actually typed ellipse …

Answer (score 11):

This will do the trick in Java

`public void foo(String parameter, Object... arguments);`

You have to add three points `...` and the `varagr` parameter must be the last in the method's signature.

Answer (score 3):

As it is written on previous answers, it is `varargs` and declared with `ellipsis` (**...**)

Moreover, you can either pass the value types and/or reference types or both mixed (google **Autoboxing**). Additionally you can use the method parameter as an array as shown with the `printArgsAlternate` method down below.

### Demo Code

```
public class VarargsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printArgs(3, true, "Hello!", new Boolean(true), new Double(25.3), 'a', new Character('X'));
        printArgsAlternate(3, true, "Hello!", new Boolean(true), new Double(25.3), 'a', new Character('X'));
    }

    private static void printArgs(Object... arguments) {
        System.out.print("Arguments: ");
        for(Object o : arguments)
            System.out.print(o + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void printArgsAlternate(Object... arguments) {
        System.out.print("Arguments: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arguments[i] + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

### Output

```
Arguments: 3 true Hello! true 25.3 a X 
Arguments: 3 true Hello! true 25.3 a X
```