# What was the alternative syntax to passing an array as a parameter in a method signature?

Tags: java

I've seen the syntax before and it's close to the form of

```
public void foo( Object object1, Object ... ){}
```

Does anyone know the exact syntax or have a link to further information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java it is called varargs.

```
public void foo(Object object, Object... objects) {
    // the 'objects' argument is an array here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it,

```
public void foo( Object object1, Object... objects ){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [this](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/using-the-varargs-language-feature.html)?

Answer (score 0):

[Java "params" in method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519752/java-params-in-method-signature)

may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, mine is a duplicate then.