# Variable arguments with different types?

Tags: java, methods, arguments

I have a List of event listeners in my code:

```
private List<EventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<EventListener>();
listeners.add(new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void someEvent(String arg1, MyClass arg2) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void someOtherEvent(AnotherClass arg1, int arg2) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Currently, I am calling the listeners using a for loop:

```
for (EventListener listener : listeners) {
    listener.someEvent("Hello world", (MyClass) myObject);
}
```

I would like to call it using a single method, like this:

```
fireEvent("someEvent", "Hello world", (MyClass) myObject);
```

Or possibly an array or something for the event arguments.

One way to do this would be to create some sort of event object, but I don't particularly want to do this as it seems messy (someone tell me if I'm wrong here; I'm inexperienced with Java). Is there a way to create a fireEvent similar to above? EventListener is an interface, if that helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java "params" in method signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519752/java-params-in-method-signature)

Comment: Similar, but not quite: that question assumes that all the arguments are the same type, and the answer would not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you can do this using java reflection:

```
public void fireEvent(String name, Object... args) {
    Method method = null;
    // 1. find method
    for (Method m : EventListener.class.getMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().equals(name)) {
            method = m;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (method == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown event method: " + name);
    }

    // 2. call method on all listeners
    for (EventListener l : listeners) {
        try {
            method.invoke(l, args);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that this is a trivial version that does not cover all eventualities like overloaded event methods etc.)

But I strongly advice do NOT do that! It's not only ugly and hard to read, it also makes your program being NOT typesafe any more! When you use the wrong name `String` or the wrong number or types of parameters, the compiler won't notice, but the program will break at runtime!

So I suggest to simply have one protected `fireXXXEvent` method for every event handler method of your listener (using a simple for loop). In your case this would be:

```
protected void fireSomeEvent(String arg1, MyClass arg2);
protected void fireSomeOtherEvent(AnotherClass arg1, int arg2);
```

Of course you can also introduce event objects (possibly by subclassing `java.util.EventObject`). But this might not necessarily reduce the number of methods in your listener (but it can - depends on the types of events you've got).

There are some fancier strategies e.g. using a generic event handler with event type objects and generic event objects as in JavaFX, but I think this is not recommended if you're not very familiar with java.

*Sidenote: Use either a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` for storing your listeners or iterate over a copy of `listeners` when firing the events otherwise you might get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if a listeners tries to remove itself from the listener list.*

Comment: Thanks. So would you recommend continuing as I'm doing it now, or creating Event objects?

Comment: I've extended my answer to provide other options.