# What does ... mean after declaring a widget type?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-typeface

I found a script to set Typeface recursively, but I am unfamiliar with the syntax used. What does "..." mean after you set a type? For example, "TextView...params". What is interesting is that I can call the method and add as many TextViews in one call as I want and all the TextViews will have the correct typeface applied to it. So my guess is that the "..." allows this, but what is this notation called and what is the official definition of its use? Here is the method I am using.

```
public static void setTextViewFont(Typeface tf, TextView...params) {
    for (TextView tv : params) {
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

I can call this method with setTextViewFont(tf, tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv6). I can keep adding as many textViews as I want, I am just not sure how this works. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Java feature called [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) that allows a parameter list, it's not specific to Android.

You can find a similar question here: [Java "params" in method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519752/java-params-in-method-signature)

Comment: Varargs! I learned a new term, thank you. I read the definition and that is exactly the behaviors I am witnessing.

Comment: @Will Eddins Please accept the answer in case you have found what you were looking for in this case, yes.