# What is the meaning Params... ? in android

Tags: android

I'm stil new with android dev, so today I stumble upon this code in [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))

```
Result doInBackground (Params... params)
```

What is the meaning of `Params...` ? is it the same as `Params`? but when using `Params` (without ...), it throw an error not override abstract.

This confuse me.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25647882/3682535) for all thats good and not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a Java concept know as `var args`. It is sugar syntax to pass array of certain type in as method argument.

So when you say

```
Result doInBackground (Integer... args)
{
  Integer [] vals=args;
}
```

and you can access values from that array.

As far as AsyncTask's methods are concerned, you can change argument type from `Params` to the type you need. `Params` is just a template which you need to change during implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This in Java is called `varargs` and is an array of params but with different syntax. you can take a look the doc about this by clicking [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519752/java-params-in-method-signature) question has an answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTask is a Class which has three methods. DoInBackground() gets called after onPreExecute(). In some cases, the onPreExecute might be returning some value. This value can be captured by doInBackground() with the Params field. 
This params canbe either Int, Strings, Collection,Context.

NOTE : Similarly with onPOstExecute(Params params). This params is the value returned in doInBackground.

If you dont have any value to return, then you dont need to use the params values in these methods.

Answer (score 2):

`Params...` here refers to parameters. The `...` is a way of representing an array.

`Result doInBackground (Params... params)`

Here this means that `params` is an array of `Params` type. By default the value the function `doInBackground` receives is stored in `params[0]`. Sometimes the function might receive another value while executing, that will be stored in higher indexes.

Hope that solves your question :-)